# Eigenvalues of $\mathbb E\pmatrix{2X&X\\ 1-X&2X}$.

Tags: matrices, random-variables

Let $X$ be a random variable between $0$ and $1$, such that: $\mathbb{E}[X]=\frac{1}{2}$.
We have a matrix:
$$A=\left(
  \begin{array}{cc}
    2X & X \\
    1-X & 2X \\
  \end{array}
\right)$$
for which
$$\mathbb{E}[A]=\mathbb E\pmatrix{2X&X\\ 1-X&2X}=\pmatrix{1&\frac{1}{2}\\ \frac{1}{2}&1}$$
The eigenvalues of $\mathbb{E}[A]$ are $1/2$ and $3/2$. My question is the following: are, the eigenvalues obtained in this way, the "mean eigenvalues" of $A$?

Thanks.

Comment: How you are defining "mean eigenvalues " of A?

Comment: Without a definition of the "mean eigenvalues" of a random matrix there is no question. The eigenvalues of $A$ are $\lambda_{\pm}=2X\pm\sqrt{X(1-X)}$ hence there is no reason to expect that $E(\lambda_{\pm})=1\pm\frac12$.

Comment: Ok, I was wrong. Where can I find these topics ("mean eigenvalues " of A)? Could you recommend me some online resource, please?

Comment: This can be a useful resource if you want to find non-asymptotic analysis of eigenvalues for random matrices http://www-personal.umich.edu/~romanv/papers/non-asymptotic-rmt-plain.pdf

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay, thank you.

Comment: Actually $E(\lambda_{pm})=1\pm\frac12$ if and only if $P(X=\frac12)=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is
$$
p_A = t^2-4X t + (5X^2-X)
$$
The eigenvalues of $A$ are
$$
\lambda_{1,2} = 2X \pm \sqrt{ 4X^2 - 5X^2+X} = 2X\pm \sqrt{X(1-X)}
$$
There expected values are
$$
\mathbb E[\lambda_{1,2}] = 1 \pm \mathbb E[\sqrt{X(1-X)}].
$$
This is equal to the eigenvalues you found only if $E[\sqrt{X(1-X)}] = \frac12$. If $X$ is uniformly distributed this expectation is $\pi/8 \ne 1/2$.

Answer (score 1):

No, you have to find the **random** eigenvalues of $A$ and then find its mean. For example here $A$ has the characteristic equation $$\lambda^2-4\lambda X+5X^2-X=0\implies \lambda=2X\pm \sqrt{X-X^2}$$ To find mean eigenvalue of $\lambda$ you need to find expectation of this quantity, which is obviously not going to be the answer you found, in general.